# Function that executes a block of code once per std::source_location where the invocation takes place

Tags: c++, c++23

I'm trying to write a function that will be called from lots of different places. Part of this function should only occur once, but "once" per filename + linenumber making the invokation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

void Bar(const std::source_location& location = std::source_location::current())
{
  // only do this once per unique location
  std::cout << location.file_name()
            << " (" << location.line() << ")"
            << std::endl;

  // but do this repeatedly
  std::cout << "call multiple times" << std::endl;
}

void Foo()
{
  std::cout << "Called" << std::endl;
  Bar();
}

int main()
{
  Bar();
  Foo();
  Foo();
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jhba98cPK (compiles under GCC 13.3 with -std=c++23)

Current output:

```
example.cpp (23)
call multiple times
Called
example.cpp (18)
call multiple times
Called
example.cpp (18)
call multiple times
```

What I want:

```
example.cpp (23)
call multiple times
Called
example.cpp (18)
call multiple times
Called
call multiple times
```

Preferably it's all rolled into a single function call so that I don't need to litter static variables around the calling site. I tried wrapping this all up into a templated function:

```
template<typename UniqueT, typename Func>
void call_once(Func& func)
{
    func();
}
```

but I can't find a way to generate a unique type per calling site. I thought maybe I could generate a unique hash per `std::source_location`, but I'm not sure how (because the "source_location" is a default parameter, and in any case, I don't know if I can calculate it at compile time). I looked into `std::call_once` but this requires that I hold a flag, which I guess can be static, but it would prevent the multiple-part of the function from occurring. At least as near as I can figure.

I'd prefer not to hold an `std::unordered_map` etc somewhere, and would much prefer it occurred compile-time if it was at all possible.

Comment: Declare a [`static std::set<std::uint_least32_t>` in `Bar()`](https://godbolt.org/z/fW8Wq8ef8) to register the line numbers that have been seen.

Comment: It'd need to be an `std::pair` to account for filenames as well. But this will eat up memory. Like I said, I'd prefer a compile-time solution if one exists. Or failing that, one that adds minimal overhead, i.e. a boolean closer to the callsights (or something, idk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case 1) Assuming file_name has bounded size (known at compile time).

The fundamental idea is to pass the `source_location` as a template parameter of `Bar` instead of a function argument. `Bar` could be rewritten as such:

```cpp
struct Runner {
    Runner(auto&& callable) { callable(); }
}

template<Location location> // <-- Location type coming later.
void Bar() {
    static Runner once{[]() {
        // code to run once.
        std::cout << location.file_name() << '(' << location.line() << ')';
        std::cout << "executed once per location on 1st Bar<location> call" << std::endl;
    }};

    // code to run multiple time.
    std::cout << "executed each time" << std::endl;
}
```

A few things about this implementation (that might be desirable or not):

- `static Runner once` initialization is thread-safe.
- static initialization is blocking: other `Bar<someLoc>` calls won't run the "each time" section until one `Bar<someLoc>` call has successfully run the "once" section.
- in case the `Runner` constructor throws, other calls of `Bar` will attempt to run the "once" section again.
- A static [std::once_flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) with a [std::call_once](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) should have the same observable behaviour (however the generated assembly seemed less optimized on gcc).

The template parameter can't directly be of type `std::source_location`, so we'll have to define a custom Location type to pass as NTTP. First let's make a string class that can be used as NTTP instead of `const char*` (these constexpr_string/fixed_string/sized_string are a common c++ metaprogramming trick):

```cpp
template<std::size_t capacity>
struct ConstexprString {
public:
    [[nodiscard]]
    consteval ConstexprString(char const* source)
        : size_{ 0 }
    {
        // basic C str functions not constexpr. Reinventing the wheel...
        while (source[size_] != '\0') {
            if (size_>= capacity) {
                throw std::invalid_argument("input string does not fit.");
            }
            content_[size_] = source[size_];
            ++size_;
        }
        // constexpr values can't have uninitialized bytes.
        if (capacity > size_) {
            std::ranges::fill_n(content_ + size_, capacity - size_, '\0');
        }
    }

    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr std::string_view view() const {
        return { content_, size_ };
    }

    // To use this class as a NTTP, member variable can't be private.
    std::size_t size_;
    char content_[capacity]; // not necessarily '\0' terminated.
};
```

Then we can define our NTTP compatible class `Location`:

```cpp
struct Location {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t fileCapacity = 128;
    static constexpr std::size_t functionCapacity = 128;

    [[nodiscard]]
    consteval Location(std::source_location const& location)
        : column_{ location.column() }
        , line_{ location.line() }
        , fileName_{ location.file_name() }
        , functionName_{ location.function_name() }
    {}

    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr std::string_view file_name() const {
        // personal take: string_view feels more "correct" than 'const char*' in modern c++.
        return fileName_.view();
    }

    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr std::string_view function_name() const {
        return functionName_.view();
    }

    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr std::uint_least32_t column() const {
        return column_;
    }

    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr std::uint_least32_t line() const {
        return line_;
    }

    // To use Location as a NTTP, member variable can't be private.
    std::uint_least32_t column_;
    std::uint_least32_t line_;
    ConstexprString<fileCapacity> fileName_;
    ConstexprString<functionCapacity> functionName_;
};
```

We're almost done with the framework. Usage:

```cpp
// last helper function
[[nodiscard]]
consteval std::source_location here(std::source_location const& loc = std::source_location::current()) {
    return loc;
}

void Foo()
{
  std::cout << "Called" << std::endl;
  Bar<here()>();
}

int main()
{
  Bar<here()>();
  Foo();
  Foo();
  return 0;
}
```

##### [**Live demo (godbolt)**](https://godbolt.org/z/zrnre93Gn).

All of this should be portable c++20.

#### Case 2) Variable string capacity.

`Location` can be made to have just the right capacity for its strings. However my solution requires `Bar` to take 2 template parameters: calling it is more verbose.

Again, let's make a NTTP compatible class to compute the sizes of the strings:

```cpp
// std::strlen isn't constexpr. Reinventing the wheel...
[[nodiscard]]
constexpr std::size_t StrLen(char const* str) {
    char const* cur = str;
    while (*cur != '\0') {
        ++cur;
    }
    return cur - str;
}

struct LocationSize {
public:
    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr LocationSize(std::source_location const& location)
        : fileLength{ StrLen(location.file_name()) }
        , functionLength{ StrLen(location.function_name()) }
    {}

    std::size_t fileLength;
    std::size_t functionLength;
};
```

Templating `Location` to use variable sized strings:

```cpp
template<LocationSize sizes>
struct Location {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t fileCapacity = sizes.fileLength;
    static constexpr std::size_t functionCapacity = sizes.functionLength;

    // rest is unchanged
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
void log(auto const& location, std::string_view message) {
    std::cout << location.file_name() << '(' << location.line() << ';' << location.column() << ')';
    std::cout << " from '" << location.function_name() << "': ";
    std::cout << message << '\n';
}

template<LocationSize ls, Location<ls> location>
void Bar()
{
    static Runner once{[]() {
        // only do this once per unique location
        log(location, "once section");
    }};

    // but do this repeatedly
    log(location, "repeat section");
}

void Foo()
{
    std::cout << "Foo Call" << std::endl;
    constexpr auto loc = here();
    Bar<loc,loc>();
}

int main()
{
    Bar<here(),here()>();
    Foo();
    Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

##### [**Live demo(godbolt)**](https://godbolt.org/z/1bn8feqT8)

The magic is happening in `template<LocationSize ls, Location<ls> location>`. Both types are convertible from `std::source_location` and should be called with the same `source_location` passed twice. The first conversion to `LocationSize ls` extracts the string sizes, and is just an intermediate value to compute the exact type of the second parameter.

Calling `Bar<here(),here()>();` in main is a bit hacky, since we're passing 2 different source_location. But it should work anyway since what really matters is that they have the same file_name/function_name strings. And the syntax is significantly more compact than declaring a constexpr variable.

#### Warning: binary size

A different `Bar` template is being instanciated at each call site, causing the usual assembly code duplication. On top of that, each `Bar` instanciation causes the template parameter `location` to be stored as a constant in the program memory, each with its own copy of file_name/function_name. Depending on your build process, file_name might be the complete absolute path of the source file...

**This is NOT zero cost.**